# Filtering a list based on an object member

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, dictionary

HI Im trying to figure out how to filter my list based on a class member, but i dont know how

Im trying to display IQueryable with filter
say this is my Request

```
public class Request
{
    [Column] public int RequestID { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Requester { get; set; }
    [Column] public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass a dictionary to my controller so the controller can process the filter and display it.

But how do I define the dictionary

```
//This isn't even the right syntax

filter = new Dictionary<What_to_put_here,What_to_put_here>
{
    {Request.Requester, "Mario"},
    {Request.DepartureTime, 05/05/2011 11:00PM}
}
```

so that later I can do something like

```
repo.Requests.where(filter.key == filter.value)
```

Is there any better ways to do it? or is this even possible?

Comment: why do you have to use dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

you can filter like

```
repo.Requests.Where(filter=>filter.RequestID == 2);
```

and

```
   repo.Requests.Where(filter=>filter.RequestID < 2 && filter.DepartureTime < DateTime.Now);
```